# Display a quad perpendicular to the screen

Tags: c++, c, opengl

When drawing a quad, it vanishes when rotation brings in a position perpendicular to the screen. Ideally what I'd like to see is (b) but I get nothing

[image]

Is there something wrong with my code ? (warning old openGL code following)

```
void draw_rect(double vector[4][3], int rgb[3], double transp)
{
    GLint is_depth, is_blend, blend_src, blend_dst; 

    glGetIntegerv(GL_DEPTH_WRITEMASK, &is_depth); 
    glGetIntegerv(GL_BLEND, &is_blend); 
    glGetIntegerv(GL_BLEND_SRC, &blend_src); 
    glGetIntegerv(GL_BLEND_DST, &blend_dst); 

    glEnable(GL_BLEND); 
    glDepthMask(0); 
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 

    // code to set the color ... 

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); 
    glVertex3v(&vector[0][0]); 
    glVertex3v(&vector[1][0]); 
    glVertex3v(&vector[2][0]); 
    glVertex3v(&vector[3][0]); 
    glEnd(); 

    if (!is_blend){ glDisable(GL_BLEND); }
    glDepthMask(is_depth); 
    glBlendFunc(blend_src, blend_dst); 
}
```

Comment: I'd say the behaviour is correct. Since you have a quad in one layer, it has no depth, so if you look at it perpendicularly, it has 0 size. Works as intended. You could make it a very shallow cube maybe.

Comment: @SinisterMJ Fair enough; I removed the word "corectly" from the title, so maybe we could focus on tips like the one you just gave

Comment: If a filled primitive (_e.g._ quad) is perpendicular to the image plane, it has no rasterized surface area. Have you considered drawing these perpendicular quads using `GL_LINES` instead? Line and point primitives always have guaranteed width.

Answer (score 2):

A quad (assuming it is defined by coplanar faces, as in this case) is by definition infinitely thin. It is correct behavior for it to be invisible when perpendicular to the camera.

The "correct" solution is to make a box rather than a single quad.

See [Drawing cube 3D using Opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106258/drawing-cube-3d-using-opengl) for an example using a cube. You'll need to tweak the vertex positions to  make the cube smaller along one dimension (probably Z), but it'll give you the effect that you're looking for.

Also, **stop using the fixed function stuff** (`glVertex`, etc.). It's been deprecated for years. Shaders aren't that difficult, and examples are easy to find via your favorite search engine.

Comment: Immediate mode (`glVertex` etc.) is orthogonal to shaders. You can use shaders in immediate mode, and you can use the fixed-function pipeline with arrays, or even buffer objects.

Answer (score 1):

try making it a line of some definite width when the quad is perpendicular to the screen